# Using loops, arrays and IEventDispatcher with URLRequest

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, events, adobe

I have a map. On this map I have points, and when you click on these points it goes to a URL.

The code setup is as follows:

- Arrays to define the movieclip
  locations and another for the urls
  (this one is an associative array).
- I then create a function loop to make
  an event listener for each point.
  When the point is clicked it will run
  another function that handles the
  URLs.
- The URL function is to grab the
  target point that has been click, use
  the url array type to find the key,
  and then throw it in to the
  URLRequest.

So far I have this code:

```
var places:Array = new Array();
places = [
 map.paulsens, map.paraburdoo, map.plutonic, map.wiluna, map.gwalia, map.wallaby,
 map.sunrise, map.moora, map.marvel, map.flyingFox, map.ernest, map.rosebery,
 map.lyell, map.renison, kalMap.kanowna, kalMap.frogsLeg, kalMap.tindals,
 kalMap.miitel, kalMap.higginsville
];

var links:Array = new Array();
links[ "paulsens" ] = "http://mywebsite.com/";
links[ "paraburdoo" ] = "http://mywebsite.com/";
links[ "plutonic" ] = "http://mywebsite.com/";
links[ "wiluna" ] = "http://mywebsite.com/";
links[ "gwalia" ] = "http://mywebsite.com/";
links[ "wallaby" ] = "http://mywebsite.com/";
links[ "sunrise" ] = "http://mywebsite.com/";
links[ "moora" ] = "http://mywebsite.com/";
links[ "marvel" ] = "http://mywebsite.com/";
links[ "flyingFox" ] = "http://mywebsite.com/";
links[ "ernest" ] = "http://mywebsite.com/";
links[ "rosebery" ] = "http://mywebsite.com/";
links[ "lyell" ] = "http://mywebsite.com/";
links[ "renision" ] = "http://mywebsite.com/";
links[ "kanowna" ] = "http://mywebsite.com/";
links[ "frogsLeg" ] = "http://mywebsite.com/";
links[ "tindals" ] = "http://mywebsite.com/";
links[ "miitel" ] = "http://mywebsite.com/";
links[ "higginsville" ] = "http://mywebsite.com/";

function listenerLoop():void {
    var i:int;
    for( i = 0; i < places.length; i++ ) {
        ( places[ i ] as IEventDispatcher ).addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, openLink );
    }
}

function openLink( event:MouseEvent ):void {
    var link:URLRequest = new URLRequest( links[ event.target ] );
    navigateToURL( link, "_blank" );
}

listenerLoop();
```

Now all works fine until I click on the point, giving me this error:

```
TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter url must be non-null.
at global/flash.net::navigateToURL()
```

at

```
navigateToURL( link, "_blank" );
```

It's obvious to me that the openLink(); function isn't doing what I want it to. I can kind of guess because event.target isn't being turned in to a string or not pulling the array's type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
var link:URLRequest = new URLRequest( links[ event.target.name ] );
```

and since you define strings for you iterator it may be better do define your links as an object in favor of an array

Comment: Ahaha, so simple a fix. Thank you Andy :)

Do you mean declare the associative array's datatype as an object rather than an array?
ie var array:Object = new Object(); ?

Answer (score 0):

Try storing the links in a `flash.utils.Dictionary` object, since it uses memory references as keys, and so you can access items doing `links[ event.target ]`.

to inizialize it, you have also to use the objects as key.

```
links[ map.lyell ] = "http://mywebsite.com/";
links[ map.renision ] = "http://mywebsite.com/";
```